# Can a prism have a square cross section?

Tags: visible-light

Prisms are usually depicted as triangles made from a transparent material such as glass or acrylic. Could a rectangle or a thick sheet of a similar material act as a prism too? I have never seen one like that. What are the implications on light passing through it?

Comment: Do you know what a prism is?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft it is a device that splits light into its different colours?

Comment: A prism is a prism. A rectangle is a rectangle.

Comment: @mcodesmart prisms are specific geometrical shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a prism does not have to be an equilateral triangle.

The operating principle of a prism is that light exhibits dispersion in some media (like some glasses or acrylic), meaning different wavelengths of light travel at different speeds, and therefore exhibit different angles of refraction for the same angle of incidence. The shape of the prism exploits this phenomenon to cause the paths of different wavelengths of light to diverge after passing into the prism and then out again.

This occurs only when the 1st interface the light passes through is not parallel to the 2nd interface. When light passes through two parallel interfaces will exit at the angle of incidence, regardless of the angle of refraction. That means the different wavelengths will emerge parallel (though slightly offset from each other), and won't diverge (see image).

Here is an example of a shape that does NOT work as a prism (unless you send the light across a corner of the slab)
[image: Light through slab]

A prism works best when the 1st and 2nd interfaces are far from parallel; this results in more divergence of the different wavelengths, and a clearer separation of the light components. There is no need for the angle between the interfaces to be 60°.

A dramatic example of that is a circular prism, such as a raindrop:

[image: Diagram of refraction and dispersion in a raindrop]

Answer (score 1):

Well in terms of geometry a cube or cuboid is a prism: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_%28geometry%29)

In terms of refraction of light, constructing a prism with a square cross section would be a waste of material. But of course, you also could use an edge of a cuboid or cube as a prism. You sometimes see light being split into its colors by such objects. You just need two non-parallel faces and the right angle of incidence.

Comment: And you need the prism material to be dispersive, else no color separation.